# IntelliJ IDEA add namespace support for auto complate

Tags: autocomplete, intellij-idea

how to add support namespaces for `jsf`, `custom libraries` and etc.

I know, i can do it in `Settings|Project settings| Schemas and DTDs`. But i have no idea what i should point in `explorer` for `URI: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html`, for example.

Comment: It will work automatically if the tag libraries you are using in the project are [added to the module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Comment: I did add `primefaces` in the module dependencies and namespace for `http://primefaces.org/ui` not worked

Comment: It would help if you prepare and share a sample project to reproduce this problem. Also specify your IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version.

Comment: I found my mistake. I did use `Community Edition` version